# Best QWidget or item to use to display a variable in a box

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I would like to ask which QWidget or which Qt GUI item would be best to use to display a variable that will change during the lifecycle of the program, in a box. The image gives a description of what I need. I want to place that box several times on my MainWindow.

[image]

I have tried QRectItem but then I was unable to display the text using a label because the label is a QWidget. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the type of the variable? Is is a string, an integer, ... ?

Comment: When you say `"...I was unable to display the text using a label because the label is a QWidget"` I assume you're referring to [this, now deleted, post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72027235/no-matching-constructor-for-initialization-of-qlabel)?  You *can* use a `QLabel` but you need to make use of [`QGraphicsProxyWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsproxywidget.html) in some form or another.  There's also [`QGraphicsSimpleTextItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicssimpletextitem.html).  You really need to provide more detail.  As it stands this is an xy-problem.

Comment: The  variable is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple QLabel with a style sheet. In the style sheet you can define a border (color, width, style), a font size, a font color and required paddings. Nevermind what is the type of the value to be displayed, you will change the text with setText method with the explicitly provided QString argument.